# redux-persist removing object methods after storing

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-persist

i am using redux-persist to store object which contains some properties and methods but when i read it it's removing the methods as it uses JSON.stringify before storing.

Answer (score 1):

With `redux-persist` you can only store serializable data, you can't (and you shouldn't) store methods.

Comment: Piggy-backing on this, you should also just put serializable values into your Redux store. See the style guide: https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions